# Compiler error calling MathNet Numerics DelimitedWriter.WriteFile

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to write a DenseMatrix object to a csv file using DelimitedWriter like so:

```
DelimitedWriter.WriteFile(originalData, "written.csv", ",");
```

A red line would appear saying that the type arguments for the method cannot be inferred from the usage and to specify the type arguments explicitly.
So I tried doing this:

```
DelimitedWriter.WriteFile<Double>(originalData, "written.csv", ",");
```

to which I got, "The best overloaded match... has some invalid arguments".

And this:

```
DelimitedWriter.WriteFile<Double>(originalData<Double>, "written.csv", ",");
```

to which I got originalData cannot be used with type arguments.
I also tried casting originalData as a Matrix (rather than DenseMatrix) but that did not work either. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an internal versioning issue with Math.NET nuget packages, you will get an error even if you try to pass in a null literal for the first argument.

I notice that Intellisense says it is expecting a `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Matrix<T>` but that in version 3.0+ of Math.NET that type is `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<T>`

You may want to try installing the specific version that the text IO extensions says it supports from the package manager console:

```
Uninstall-Package MathNet.Numerics -Force
Install-Package MathNet.Numerics -Version 2.5.0
```

That worked for me. I'm not sure when the breaking changes were made, presumably with version 3.0. You should report this as an issue to the maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the v3 versions of the Data extensions with the v3 versions of Math.NET Numerics.

As of today e.g. use the [MathNet.Numerics.Data.Text v3.0.0-beta02](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.Data.Text/3.0.0-beta02) package. You may need to allow pre-release packages in NuGet or this version may not appear though. Unfortunately there is no full v3 release of that package yet because of some pending changes.

Do *not* downgrade to Math.NET Numerics v2.